# How do I convert a string to enum in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have defined the following enum in TypeScript:

```
enum Color{
    Red, Green
}
```

Now in my function I receive color as a string. I have tried the following code:

```
var green= "Green";
var color : Color = <Color>green; // Error: can't convert string to enum
```

How can I convert that value to an enum?

Comment: Came here trying to get the enum from a string.
enum MyEnum { A = 1, B = 5 }
String x = 'B';
MyEnum[x].toString() // value 5
MyEnum[x] // value B
hope it helps

Answer (score 809, accepted):

Enums in TypeScript 0.9 are string+number based. You should not need type assertion for simple conversions:

```
enum Color{
    Red, Green
}

// To String
 var green: string = Color[Color.Green];

// To Enum / number
var color : Color = Color[green];
```

[Try it online](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=enum%20Color%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Red%2C%20Green%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20To%20String%0D%0A%20var%20green%3A%20string%20%3D%20Color%5BColor.Green%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20To%20Enum%0D%0Avar%20color%20%3A%20Color%20%3D%20Color%5Bgreen%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)

I have documentation about this and other Enum patterns in my OSS book : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/enums

Make sure to use this if you are using the typescript flag `--noImplicitAny`:

```
var color : Color = Color[green as keyof typeof Color];
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `--noImplicitAny` (in VS unchecked "Allow implicit 'any' types"). It produces `error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.` For me this worked: `var color: Color = (<any>Color)[green];` (tested with version 1.4)

Comment: @Vojta said right. Its not working in VS 2012. This one worked but var color: Color = (<any>Color)[green];

Comment: Regarding `noImplicitAny`, see [closed issue 9234](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9234), basically it's because some strings (e.g. "0") will act as integers in the index.

Comment: Note that this won't work if the enum is defined as "const"

Comment: It doesn't work here either, the official documentation seems to confirm that: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#string-enums

Comment: Note also that this doesn't work for string-valued enum members, see https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/10/27/typescript-2-4-string-enums

Comment: Or when the enum has bitwise operations representing a collection.

Comment: Make sure to use this if --noImplicitAny

`var color : Color = Color[green as keyof typeof Color];`

Comment: green should not be "any" string but `keyof typeof Color`, otherwise the convertion back is not guaranteed

Comment: why is there a colon, wtf

Answer (score 286):

As of Typescript 2.1 string keys in enums are strongly typed. `keyof typeof` is used to get info about available string keys ([1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)):

```
enum Color{
    Red, Green
}

let typedColor: Color = Color.Green;
let typedColorString: keyof typeof Color = "Green";

// Error "Black is not assignable ..." (indexing using Color["Black"] will return undefined runtime)
typedColorString = "Black";

// Error "Type 'string' is not assignable ..." (indexing works runtime)
let letColorString = "Red";
typedColorString = letColorString;

// Works fine
typedColorString = "Red";

// Works fine
const constColorString = "Red";
typedColorString = constColorString

// Works fine (thanks @SergeyT)
let letColorString = "Red";
typedColorString = letColorString as keyof typeof Color;

typedColor = Color[typedColorString];
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types

Comment: So we can use typecast: `let s = "Green"; let typedColor = <keyof typeof Color> s;`

Comment: Yep, and replacing `let` with `const` will work without casting. Updated example to clarify this. Thanks @SergeyT

Comment: `typedColorString = Color["Black"];` now returns `error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'`

Comment: A one line answer: `const color: Color = Color[colorString as keyof typeof Color];`

Comment: @Dominik You need a string enum

Answer (score 222):

If you provide string values to your enum, a straight cast works just fine.

```
enum Color {
  Green = "Green",
  Red = "Red"
}

const color = "Green";
const colorEnum = color as Color;
```

Comment: This could be misleading as it doesn't guard against invalid colors.  `const colorEnum = "Blue" as Color` won't error, and you would be left thinking that `colorEnum` is OK. But if you were to `console.log` it, you'd see "Blue".  [Artru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41548441/182875) is nice, because `colorEnum` will be `undefined` - and you can then check for that specifically.

Comment: Pair this with a `Object.values(Enum).indexOf(value) >= 0` check, to see that it's a valid value.

Answer (score 169):

```
enum Color{
    Red, Green
}

// To String
 var green: string = Color[Color.Green];

// To Enum / number
var color : Color = Color[green as keyof typeof Color]; //Works with --noImplicitAny
```

This example works with `--noImplicitAny` in TypeScript

Sources:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13775#issuecomment-276381229 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types

Comment: I don't know why, but this solution does not work on on a [const enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums) 

(using Typescript 3.8.3)

Comment: @Robin-Hoodie A bit late to the party (but for the benefit of other latecomers), but const enums are compiled out of the code completely, so the runtime code has no references to the enum keys, only their literal values.  It therefore has no way to map those values back to the enum keys.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: Only answer that makes invalid values `undefined`

Answer (score 99):

Given you use typescript:
Many of the solutions above might not work or are overly complex.

**Situation**: The strings are not the same as the enum values (casing differs)

```
enum Color {
  Green = "green",
  Red = "red"
}
```

Just use:

```
const color = "green" as Color
```

**Please note that this does not guarantee a valid enum.**

Comment: One of the reasons I would want to use enums is to restrict to valid cases. In this example I could do `const color = 'banana' as Color` and it still parses fine, but the color is no longer valid.

Comment: @DanielWood it's a good remark, I added it to my answer earlier.

Comment: @DanielWood Good point! What is the correct solution to prevent what you're saying?

Answer (score 87):

### Typescript 1.x

If you are sure that an input string has an exact match with Color enum then use:

```
const color: Color = (<any>Color)["Red"];
```

In the case where an input string may not match Enum, use:

```
const mayBeColor: Color | undefined = (<any>Color)["WrongInput"];
if (mayBeColor !== undefined){
     // TypeScript will understand that mayBeColor is of type Color here
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Color%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Red%2C%20Green%0A%7D%0Aconst%20color%3A%20Color%20%3D%20%3Cany%3EColor%5B%22Green%22%5D%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22color%3A%20%22%20%2B%20color)%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mayBeColor%3A%20Color%20%7C%20undefined%20%3D%20%3Cany%3EColor%5B%22WrongInput%22%5D%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22non%20existing%20color%3A%20%22%20%2B%20mayBeColor)%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mayBeColor2%3A%20Color%20%7C%20undefined%20%3D%20%3Cany%3EColor%5B%22Green%22%5D%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22existing%20color%3A%20%22%2BmayBeColor2)%3B)

---

If we do not cast `enum` to `<any>` type then TypeScript will show the error:

> Element implicitly has 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

It means that by default the TypeScript Enum type works with number indexes, i.e.
`let c = Color[0]`, but not with string indexes like `let c = Color["string"]`. This is a known restriction by the Microsoft team for the more general issue *[Object string indexes](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/535628)*.

### Typescript 2.x-4x

TypeScript moved to the `keyof typeof` concept.

If some uses string value enums:

```
enum Color {
  Green = "GRN",
  Red = "RD"
}
```

then there is the language solution to map keys to values (Color.Green -> "GRN") just by accessing an enum member, but there is no simple way to do the reverse ("GRN" -> Color.Green). From [reverse-mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings):

> Keep in mind that string enum members do not get a reverse mapping
> generated at all.

A possible solution is to manually check values and cast the value to the enum. Please notice that it will work only with string enums.

```
function enumFromStringValue<T> (enm: { [s: string]: T}, value: string): T | undefined {
  return (Object.values(enm) as unknown as string[]).includes(value)
    ? value as unknown as T
    : undefined;
}

enumFromStringValue(Color, "RD"); // Color.Red
enumFromStringValue(Color, "UNKNOWN"); // undefined
enumFromStringValue(Color, "Red"); // undefined
```

Comment: You can also cast to <keyof typeof Color>. Also "0" is wrong input too but will not return undefined, so check typeof mayBeColor==='number'

Comment: @Quentin2 what about a numeric string? ie `typeof '0'` should be `string`

Comment: Note that this is not very safe. `(<any>Color)["hasOwnProperty"]` will work but not the way you expect.

Comment: @Mat, why? Why will it work but not in the expected way?

Answer (score 39):

### Simplest approach

```
enum Color { Red, Green }

const c1 = Color["Red"]
const redStr = "Red" // important: use `const`, not mutable `let`
const c2 = Color[redStr]
```

This works both for [numeric](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) and [string](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) enums. No need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

### Unknown enum strings

Simple, unsafe variant

```
const redStrWide: string = "Red" // wide, unspecific typed string
const c3 = Color[redStrWide as keyof typeof Color]
```

Safe variant with checks

```
const isEnumName = <T>(str: string, _enum: T): str is Extract<keyof T, string> =>
    str in _enum
const enumFromName = <T>(name: string, _enum: T) => {
    if (!isEnumName(name, _enum)) throw Error() // here fail fast as an example
    return _enum[name]
}
const c4 = enumFromName(redStrWide, Color)
```

### Convert string enum values

[String enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) don't have a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) (in contrast to numeric ones). We can create a lookup helper to convert an enum value string to an enum type:

```
enum ColorStr { Red = "red", Green = "green" }

const c5_by_name = ColorStr["Red"] // ✅ this works
const c5_by_value_error = ColorStr["red"] // ❌ , but this not

const enumFromValue = <T extends Record<string, string>>(val: string, _enum: T) => {
    const enumName = (Object.keys(_enum) as Array<keyof T>).find(k => _enum[k] === val)
    if (!enumName) throw Error() // here fail fast as an example
    return _enum[enumName]
}

const c5 = enumFromValue("red", ColorStr)
```

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTCwCgQAgRgSigZwJYFsAOAbApogLlAIbroBOA9oQMYAWEIE2AdgK6pQDC5m5pUA3lABK2ACYAaKAHFS2ZlAC+EKuSb4oVGFAC8nbrwDaAIhGijAXWWr1s0QGU8fXSbFGo0NOl55CTPAC4oFkRsKAADFTU8MMkmcgJUFh8AIxxwnGirKI0AJh09HlIDWwdSS3B6MEhgKByEFiYAaziAdyYoZjYkR2QmAHNESqybMVKAdWRRbED8Ul6+-JczdxqWyexJBsR0bCpkADNkKig8AE8d0W65-ohK2sIEFAwcTbVCfdCAN0I53zxhghUADM+S4hWKo0cEymREQUEa2FO5H2J3O2GRBV45TuOWSj3eXx+yD+AKgyEQAFFWKgAHKEVChXQAHgAKgA+AAUsxmPX6kgA+p1UIEWXAeXxyVAKQAPRzUPBMhFIlEsySzeZsnRsiBQXVXMntQXU0lCgBiFFp9MZUFZnKYVvF8wFQpFCG0mv4Or1BygHIAhOSqWw6QyOfaGc7qXAEHgaBQWlLSBRSByENAaNhZFB9oRkJhs4R1IWiO1sNL6VhsF7dbI8CxSIahQZw9hykoKuBIuoqAAWfJmi0h7AckpQ9aSMG8OC3ap3IEILhMT6Zgjq-odalQb6YFihIbgIWY0ilATCMSLWxGSQyOTtZx9WTMNzt0lUACs-KVoP0x8cxlMFgrFAgCg5CcNCSi0vCNIMnbWICH6Zsm36FKUxiXuYQGADLkUCSMkSRgZKcT-B2XYEAO5CoAAaoQO7WqyHSyswohwiIKikKITJrn0aq8n0bKctujp8lARpsK6WoCNWGhwRuwZWvkHIAPLJAAVrseAAHRKogHKiagCDFgAgkmhCnIqiIYuycAaYcTCiByjQSXpBiNBh2juVuNHTuAepkii-pCkOMZxuQCYUkmvCpkBGZZjmeYFkWcK+AxFY4FJtb1o21IGIFVptjOpEaG+-bUuaFHUbRHJGJeE4-qUcBAA)

Comment: My enum value is of type `number` and doing it like `EnumHere[stringVar]` just says: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)

Answer (score 34):

I got it working using the following code.

```
var green= "Green";
var color : Color= <Color>Color[green];
```

Answer (score 33):

This note relates to basarat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17381004/81723), not the original question.

I had an odd issue in my own project where the compiler was giving an error roughly equivalent to "cannot convert string to Color" using the equivalent of this code:

```
var colorId = myOtherObject.colorId; // value "Green";
var color: Color = <Color>Color[colorId]; // TSC error here: Cannot convert string to Color.
```

I found that the compiler type inferencing was getting confused and it thought that `colorId` was an enum value and not an ID. To fix the problem I had to cast the ID as a string:

```
var colorId = <string>myOtherObject.colorId; // Force string value here
var color: Color = Color[colorId]; // Fixes lookup here.
```

I'm not sure what caused the issue but I'll leave this note here in case anyone runs into the same problem I did.

Comment: Thank you! This is a pretty silly issue and hard to figure out what the problem is.Maybe Typescript should consider coming up with a better way of handling enums.

Answer (score 19):

If the TypeScript compiler knows that the type of variable is string then this works:

```
let colorName : string = "Green";
let color : Color = Color[colorName];
```

Otherwise you should explicitly convert it to a string (to avoid compiler warnings):

```
let colorName : any = "Green";
let color : Color = Color["" + colorName];
```

At runtime both solutions will work.

Comment: why not just use typecast `<string>colorName` instead of `"" + colorName`?

Answer (score 18):

I also ran into the same compiler error.  Just a slight shorter variation of Sly_cardinal's approach.

```
var color: Color = Color[<string>colorId];
```

Comment: As an addition: In case you have a typescript enum filled by a javascript layer that serialized the enum as string (say for example Asp Web API via AngularJS) you can do

`myProp.color = Color[<string><any>myProp.color]`

Cheers

Comment: This must be the recognized answer.

Answer (score 15):

I was looking for an answer that can get an `enum` from a `string`, but in my case, the enums values had different string values counterpart.  The OP had a simple enum for `Color`, but I had something different:

```
enum Gender {
  Male = 'Male',
  Female = 'Female',
  Other = 'Other',
  CantTell = "Can't tell"
}
```

When you try to resolve `Gender.CantTell` with a `"Can't tell"` string, it returns `undefined` with the original answer.

#### Another answer

Basically, I came up with another answer, strongly inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450434/45001):

```
export const stringToEnumValue = <ET, T>(enumObj: ET, str: string): T =>
  (enumObj as any)[Object.keys(enumObj).filter(k => (enumObj as any)[k] === str)[0]];
```

#### Notes

- We take the *first result* of `filter`, assuming the client is passing a valid string from the enum.  If it's not the case, `undefined` will be returned.
- We cast `enumObj` to `any`, because with TypeScript 3.0+ (currently using TypeScript 3.5), the `enumObj` is resolved as `unknown`.

#### Example of Use

```
const cantTellStr = "Can't tell";

const cantTellEnumValue = stringToEnumValue<typeof Gender, Gender>(Gender, cantTellStr);
console.log(cantTellEnumValue); // Can't tell
```

Note: And, as someone pointed out in a comment, I also wanted to use the `noImplicitAny`.

### Updated version

No cast to `any` and proper typings.

```
export const stringToEnumValue = <T, K extends keyof T>(enumObj: T, value: string): T[keyof T] | undefined =>
  enumObj[Object.keys(enumObj).filter((k) => enumObj[k as K].toString() === value)[0] as keyof typeof enumObj];
```

Also, the updated version has a easier way to call it and is more readable:

```
stringToEnumValue(Gender, "Can't tell");
```

Comment: ```Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'T[K]'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Maybe a bit more readable:  
`const stringToEnumByValue = <T>(enumObj: Object, value: string): T | undefined =>
  Object.values(enumObj).find((v) => v === value);`  
and  
`const stringToEnumByKey = <T>(enumObj: Object, value: string): T | undefined =>
  Object.values(enumObj)[Object.keys(DeliveryState).indexOf(value)];`

Answer (score 10):

I needed to know how to loop over enum values (was testing lots of permutations of several enums) and I found this to work well:

```
export enum Environment {
    Prod = "http://asdf.com",
    Stage = "http://asdf1234.com",
    Test = "http://asdfasdf.example.com"
}

Object.keys(Environment).forEach((environmentKeyValue) => {
    const env = Environment[environmentKeyValue as keyof typeof Environment]
    // env is now equivalent to Environment.Prod, Environment.Stage, or Environment.Test
}
```

Source: https://blog.mikeski.net/development/javascript/typescript-enums-to-from-string/

Comment: This answer is genious! Love it. Especially the way you make an enum out of the string. This can save you so much typing when testing enums or other cases.

Comment: Yes, I use this with Jest's `each` to test every single enum case with only one method

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR:
Either:

- Make a function which parse and convert the string value into an enum.
- If you need the key name given the value, don't use a TS enum.

At first, an enum is a mapping between a human readable name and a value, this is how it is made for.

Default values:
TS will by default ensure you do have a unique value for the defined keys of the enum.

This

```js
enum Color {
    Red, Green
}
```

Is equivalent to

```js
enum Color {
    Red = 0,
    Green = 1
}
```

The transpiled js code of both will be

```js
"use strict";
var Color;
(function (Color) {
    Color[Color["Red"] = 0] = "Red";
    Color[Color["Green"] = 1] = "Green";
})(Color || (Color = {}));
```

As this is unreadable, here is the resulting object once created:

```js
{0: 'Red', 1: 'Green', Red: 0, Green: 1}
```

This object is having string and number properties (there cannot be any collision because you cannot defined an enum key as number). TS is cool enough to generate an object containing both the mapping key -> value and [value -> key](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings).

Thanks god this is a bijective mapping i.e. a every unique value is having it's unique key (and therefore the opposite is true as well)

Now comes the troubles, what if I force using the same value ?

```js
enum Color {
    Red = 0,
    Green = 0
}
```

This is the resulting created js object

```js
{0: 'Green', Red: 0, Green: 0}
```

We do not have the bijection anymore, (this is surjectif), there is no magic mapping `0 : ['Green', 'Red']`. Only `0 : 'Green'` and we lost the `0 : 'Red'`

Takeway: TS will always try to put the reverse map (value -> key) when the values are numbers.

Now as you may know, you can also define [string values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) within an enum, let's change only the Green value to "Green"

```js
enum Color {
    Red = 0,
    Green = "GREEN"
}
```

Here is the resulting js object

```js
{0: 'Red', Red: 0, Green: 'GREEN'}
```

As you can see, Typescript is not generating the mapping value -> key.
And it will not because you might end up with a collision between a value and a key name. Remember: a key cannot be a number therefore when the value is a number there is no risk of collision.

This makes you understand that you should not rely on the value -> key mapping of an enum. The mapping could simply be inexistant or inaccurate.

Again, an enum is, and should only be considered as, a human readable name to a value. In [some case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums) ts will not even generate any reverse mapping at all. This is the case when you define an enum const.

A const enum is a pure compilation time enum, TS will replace the use of the enum with its corresponding value at the transpilation

For [instance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgYRAGxAJxgbwFgAoGMmAJTgBMYBeGABgBoTyYBxHOBemAIg4UAosIBy-EgF8SJIA):

```js
const enum Color {
    Red = 0,
    Green = "GREEN"
}
```

Is transpiled to

```js
"use strict";
```

So just to say… nothing because "use strict"; is not even related to what we wrote.

Here is the same example with a usage:

```js
const enum Color {
    Red = 0,
    Green = "GREEN"
}
console.log(Color.Green);
```

Is transpiled to

```js
"use strict";
console.log("GREEN" /* Green */);
```

As you can see, the Color.Green is replaced by "GREEN" in place by the transpiler.

So back to the original question, how do you convert a string into an enum ?

**Parser solution:**
I'm sorry but the only clean way I recommend is writing a function, using a switch case is a clever way to achieve this.

```js
function parseColorName(color: string): Color {
  switch (color) {
    case 'Red': return Color.Red;
    case 'Green': return Color.Green;
    default: throw new Error('unknown color');
  }
}
```

**Custom enum solution:**

Note that TS enums are opaque, meaning that there is no way for the compiler to type the value properly. For this reason (and especially when you need to use reverse mapping) I would recommend doing your own enum as follow:

```js
export const ColorType = {
  RED: 'Red',
  GREEN: 'Green',
} as const;

export type ColorType = typeof ColorType[keyof typeof ColorType];
```

The following is safe (`color` can only take a valid known value). In short, you are relying on string unions instead of an enum value.

```js
const color: ColorType= "Green";
// And if you need to create a color from the enum like value:
const anotherColor: ColorType = ColorType.RED;
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're dealing with TypeScript 4.1+ and string enums, and you want a simple string-to-Enum converter with compile-time and run-time safety, the following works well:

```js
export const asEnum = <
  T extends { [key: string]: string },
  K extends keyof T & string
>(
  enumObject: T,
  value: `${T[K]}`
): T[K] => {
  if (Object.values(enumObject).includes(value)) {
    return (value as unknown) as T[K];
  } else {
    throw new Error('Value provided was not found in Enum');
  }
};

enum Test {
  hey = 'HEY',
}

const test1 = asEnum(Test, 'HEY');   // no complaints here
const test2 = asEnum(Test, 'HE');    // compile-time error
const test3 = asEnum(Test, 'HE' as any); // run-time error
```

Answer (score 9):

Almost all answers use unsafe casts (`as` or `is`). This one doesn't:

```js
enum Color {
    Red = "red",
    Green = "green"
}

const colorsMap = new Map<string,Color>(Object.values(Color).map((v) => [v,v]))

function parseColor(volumeData: string): Color | undefined {
    return colorsMap.get(volumeData)
}

const color = parseColor("red")
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a lot of mixed information in this question, so let's cover the whole implementation for TypeScript 2.x+ in *Nick's Guide to Using Enums in Models with TypeScript*.

This guide is for: people who are creating client-side code that's ingesting a set of known strings from the server that would be conveniently modeled as an Enum on the client side.

## Define the enum

Let's start with the enum. It should look something like this:

```
export enum IssueType {
  REPS = 'REPS',
  FETCH = 'FETCH',
  ACTION = 'ACTION',
  UNKNOWN = 'UNKNOWN',
}
```

Two thing of note here:

1. We're explicitly declaring these as string-backed enum cases which allows us to instantiate them with strings, not some other unrelated numbers.
2. We've added an option that may or may not exist on our server model: `UNKNOWN`. This can be handled as `undefined` if you prefer, but I like to avoid `| undefined` on types whenever possible to simplify handling.

The great thing about having an `UNKNOWN` case is that you can be really obvious about it in code and make styles for unknown enum cases bright red and blinky so you know you're not handling something correctly.

## Parse the enum

You might be using this enum embedded in another model, or all alone, but you're going to have to parse the string-y typed enum from JSON or XML (ha) into your strongly typed counterpart. When embedded in another model, this parser lives in the class constructor.

```
parseIssueType(typeString: string): IssueType {
  const type = IssueType[typeString];
  if (type === undefined) {
    return IssueType.UNKNOWN;
  }

  return type;
}
```

If the enum is properly parsed, it'll end up as the proper type. Otherwise, it'll be `undefined` and you can intercept it and return your `UNKNOWN` case. If you prefer using `undefined` as your unknown case, you can just return any result from the attempted enum parsing.

From there, it's only a matter of using the parse function and using your newly strong typed variable.

```
const strongIssueType: IssueType = parseIssueType('ACTION');
// IssueType.ACTION
const wrongIssueType: IssueType = parseIssueType('UNEXPECTED');
// IssueType.UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be not correct or, at least, not generalizable. It works because your keys equal the strings they got assigned. If they, like in my case, differ, however, this does not work. In the words of the [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings): *"Keep in mind that string enum members do not get a reverse mapping generated at all."* Your code will compile to something like `IssueType["REPS"]="REPS"`. If you had defined your enum a little different, say, `REPS="reps"` this would yield `IssueType["REPS"]="reps"` which would...

Comment: ...always return `IssueType.UNKNOWN` because there is no key `reps` in your enum. Too bad, I still found no working solution for this since my strings contain hyphens which makes them unusable as keys.

Comment: Finally, I found a solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44906580/4235784) by convincing the compiler that this was not a string enum. It might be worth editing this info into your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

For TS 3.9.x

```
var color : Color = Color[green as unknown as keyof typeof Color];
```

Comment: Neat! It seems to work without the `as unknown` part too!

Answer (score 7):

For Typescript >= 4 this code worked:

```
enum Color{
    Red, Green
}

// Conversion :
var green= "Green";
var color : Color = green as unknown as Color;
```

Comment: this is not safe, use this approach if you are 100% sure that var green holds a value of enum Color.

Comment: This saved.. But I'm sure Typescript designers were smoking something while writing the specs 

Answer (score 5):

**Enum**

```
enum MyEnum {
    First,
    Second,
    Three
}
```

**Sample usage**

```
const parsed = Parser.parseEnum('FiRsT', MyEnum);
// parsed = MyEnum.First 

const parsedInvalid= Parser.parseEnum('other', MyEnum);
// parsedInvalid = undefined
```

**Ignore case sensitive parse**

```
class Parser {
    public static parseEnum<T>(value: string, enumType: T): T[keyof T] | undefined {
        if (!value) {
            return undefined;
        }

        for (const property in enumType) {
            const enumMember = enumType[property];
            if (typeof enumMember === 'string') {
                if (enumMember.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()) {
                    const key = enumMember as string as keyof typeof enumType;
                    return enumType[key];
                }
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anybody who has enum like me should put `return enumType[property];` in a case when your enum item looks like `Skills = "anyvalue"`

Comment: @neustart47 could you please to ask  the question?

Comment: it's not a question. I just mentioned some changes for anybody who is searching for the same case as I have. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

In short, it is impossible but I **hate** forced assertion using `as`. This is what I recommend.

```js
enum Color {
  Red,
  Green
}
```

Create a map but optimize the creation such that you don't do this often.

```js
const reverse = new Map(Object.values(Color).map(item => [item.toString(), item]))
```

Now dump that function and just use the `reverseMap` to get the color enum.

```js
const colorText: string = "Red"
const colorEnum: Color | undefined = reverse.get(colorText)
```

note the potential `undefined`, since you are converitng a text to an enum, you MUST verify it explicityly. This solution also allows you to supply a default by using

```js
const colorWithFallback: Color = reverse.get("Kind of Yellow") || Color.Red
```

Answer (score 4):

Enums created in the way you did are compiled into an object that stores both forward `(name -> value)` and reverse `(value -> name)` mappings. As we can observe from this chrome devtools screenshot:

[image]

Here is an example of how dual mapping works and how to cast from one to another:

```
enum Color{
    Red, Green
}
// To Number
var greenNr: number = Color['Green'];
console.log(greenNr); // logs 1

// To String
var greenString: string = Color[Color['Green']];  // or Color[Color[1]
console.log(greenString); // logs Green

// In your example

// recieve as Color.green instead of the string green
var green: string = Color[Color.Green];  

// obtain the enum number value which corresponds to the Color.green property
var color: Color = (<any>Color)[green];  

console.log(color); // logs 1
```

Answer (score 4):

**Typescript 3.9** propsal

```
enum Color{ RED, GREEN }

const color = 'RED' as Color;
```

easy peasy... lemon squeezy!

Comment: this is unsafe, `'BANANA' as Color` will also pass

Comment: I'm still getting downvoted, the question asked is:
 "How can I convert that value to an enum?"

So this is an answer, may be not the perfect one, but in that case it's better to explicitly tell why it not. There are lots of solutions, probably most of them are good, depending on the situation.

Comment: if the question is "how do I exit a program" *an* answer is "throw an Error and don't catch it". However it's a bad answer. This is similar, this way completely removes the benefit a type system brings by manually overriding it.

Imagine having to debug a system where somewhere someone used `'YELLOW' as Color`, but in the meantime yellow was removed as a Color. Typescript is supposed to catch bugs like this, but won't if you manually override it.

Comment: I totally agree with you @dtech, probably my knowledge of TS doesn't go that far, I tought that the code above would have setup everything properly (types included). When I posted it, there wasn't any other simple solution, as far as I can remeber. Looking at this thread I can see a bit of confusion around the topic, it should be easier in my opinion. How would you answer to OP ?

Answer (score 4):

Most of these answers seems overly complex to me...

You could simply create a parse function on the enum that expects one of the keys as arguments. When new colors are added no other changes are necessary

```
enum Color { red, green}

// Get the keys 'red' | 'green' (but not 'parse')
type ColorKey = keyof Omit<typeof Color, 'parse'>;

namespace Color {
  export function parse(colorName: ColorKey ) {
    return Color[colorName];
  }
}

// The key 'red' exists as an enum so no warning is given
Color.parse('red');  // == Colors.red

// Without the 'any' cast you would get a compile-time warning
// Because 'foo' is not one of the keys in the enum
Color.parse('foo' as any); // == undefined

// Creates warning:
// "Argument of type '"bar"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"red" | "green"'"
Color.parse('bar');
```

Comment: beautiful solution

Comment: To note that this solution doesn't work with string enums. I.e. enum Color { red = 'R', green = 'G'} Color.parse('R')

Answer (score 4):

It works for me in TypeScript 4.4.3 [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/ATDGHsDsGcBdjgJwJaQOYBVwFFIFcBbANQEMAbPAU2AF5gAeDYSgD1ksgBNpgAlSiIk70kqNABoEsFOgB8kgNLM2HbsADWlAJ7gAZsAyyAFACgQIDoQDyAIwBWALgPiz5gG7kqT0ehcgAlE4YANqaOvoYALrAAD7AeFyUuqiUnLSyrhb4BLZ2wZnmuQKwAHRh0EaWOfb%20Jclk7Iim5i3ARur%206czZuaHAJDwKkSWw4ADK0mJGnTSzwB4UlH6t-sEADNEDGtp6wLBaAA6Uu1W5BZEA3CauVcAAwuBk4IjAAN4F-Gl0AOSIqd-LEAAcT%20HFowG%20aFBkABrgAvtcQBAYPA-tA8A0AIzgnyYHDZUiLIwPJ6ISTfLSUMhPADu338F2AAHomfFEslIKlXMi4MA0RjYAAmHGTdBYXCEQlUYmPZ7kqGUDj0xks%206yxAlEGKyCIsBQaCPSglJ5oIz8rGdVUJThJFJfNk2jlcpH6w3G8Cm81Cy2sknPTXQ8EAIgVHCDQA).

```
  const stringToEnumValue = <T extends Record<string, string>, K extends keyof T>(
    enumObj: T,
    value: string,
  ): T[keyof T] | undefined =>
    enumObj[
      Object.keys(enumObj).filter(
        (k) => enumObj[k as K].toString() === value,
      )[0] as keyof typeof enumObj
    ];

  enum Color {
    Red = 'red',
    Green = 'green',
  }

  const result1 = stringToEnumValue(Color, 'yellow'); // undefined
  const result2 = stringToEnumValue(Color, 'green'); // Color.Green

  console.log(result1) // undefined = undefined
  console.log(result2) // Color.Green = "green"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

> var color : Color = (Color as any)["Green];

That works fine for 3.5.3 version

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in type guarding an what would otherwise be a `string` (which is how I came across this issue), this might work for you:

```
enum CurrencyCode {
  cad = "cad",
  eur = "eur",
  gbp = "gbp",
  jpy = "jpy",
  usd = "usd",
}

const createEnumChecker = <T extends string, TEnumValue extends string>(
  enumVariable: { [key in T]: TEnumValue }
) => {
  const enumValues = Object.values(enumVariable);
  return (value: string | number | boolean): value is TEnumValue =>
    enumValues.includes(value);
};

const isCurrencyCode = createEnumChecker(CurrencyCode);

const input: string = 'gbp';

let verifiedCurrencyCode: CurrencyCode | null = null;
// verifiedCurrencyCode = input;
// ^ TypeError: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CurrencyCode | null'.

if (isCurrencyCode(input)) {
  verifiedCurrencyCode = input; // No Type Error 
}
```

Solution is taken from this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30611) discussing generic Enums

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers provided do not offer broad support for Enums. Granted the OP requested to get the Enum only from a string value, but Enums also allow other values.

```
interface StandardEnum<T> {
    [id: string]: T | string;
    [nu: number]: string;
}

/**
 * Converts the given representation of the value of one enumerated constant to an equivalent enumerated type.
 *
 * @param type - An enumeration type
 * @param value - A value to convert
 */
export const genericValueToEnum = <T, K extends StandardEnum<T>> (
    type: StandardEnum<T>,
    value: K[keyof K]
): T | undefined => {
    const keys = Object.keys(type); // ...but, not really.
    const values = Object.values(type)
        // Filter enum member names because `Object.values()` includes them.
        .filter((value) => !(
            typeof value === 'string' &&
            keys.includes(value) &&
            type[value] !== value
        ));

    return values.includes(value)
        ? value as unknown as T
        : undefined;
}
```

This will work for all enums no matter how complex (or odd), so long they're not flagged.

```
enum OddEnum {
    None = -1,
    No = 0,
    Yes = 1,
    Twenty = '20'
    Other = 'Other',
    MORE = 'More',
};

genericValueToEnum(OddEnum, -1); // => -1 as OddEnum;
genericValueToEnum(OddEnum, 'Other'); // => 'Other' as OddEnum;
genericValueToEnum(OddEnum, 'MORE'); // => undefined;
```

Comment: I think the question is how to string "MORE" convert to `OddEnum.More`, and `genericValueToEnum` does not solve this. If you call `genericValueToEnum(Color, "Red")`, it will return `undefined`.

Comment: `MORE` in my example is only the key. However, in the OP's example enum, `Green` is is both the key and value. Enums are intended to work on their value, rather than the key.

Comment: Yep, and the question is how to Key given as a string "Key" convert to the MyEnum.Key. I mean, your answer is not relevant at all.

Comment: > the question is how to Key given as a string "Key" <

Hum... I'm not sure why you think so, given that "key" is mentioned no where by the OP. Anyway, I still stand by my position that needing working with Enum in that way is likely due to an architecting issue.

Answer (score 1):

other variation can be

```
const green= "Green";

const color : Color = Color[green] as Color;
```

Comment: This generates TypeScript error:  TS7015 (TS) Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple EnumUtil, which may help you. The only thing I cannot eliminate is that we need to pass the enum two times. It validates the input on parsing.

Sample Usage

```js
enum NamesEnum {
  Bill = 'Bill Hogwards',
  John = 'John Doe',
}

//the idea is to init the util for a given enum once for the whole project and reuse it
const namesEnumUtil = EnumUtil.forString<NamesEnum>(NamesEnum);
const value = namesEnumUtil.parse("Bill Hogwards"); //parse requires string as an input
const allValues = namesEnumUtil.getAllValues(); //returns string[]

const wrongValue = namesEnumUtil.parse("Value is not there"); //this line will throw Error
```

[Typescript playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQLk7W)

The Enum Util Class itself:

```
type EnumType = 'string' | 'number';

type GetResultType<T extends EnumType> = T extends 'string'
  ? string
  : T extends 'number'
  ? number
  : never;

class EnumUtil<TEnum, TEnumType extends EnumType> {
  private constructor(
    private readonly theEnum: any,
    private readonly enumType: TEnumType
  ) {}

  static forString<TEnum>(theEnum: any) {
    return new EnumUtil<TEnum, 'string'>(theEnum, 'string');
  }

  static forInt<TEnum>(theEnum: any) {
    return new EnumUtil<TEnum, 'number'>(theEnum, 'number');
  }

  getAllValues(): Array<GetResultType<TEnumType>> {
    const result = Object.keys(this.theEnum).map(
      (key) => this.theEnum[key] as GetResultType<TEnumType>
    );
    if (this.enumType === 'string') {
      return result;
    } else if (this.enumType === 'number') {
      return result
        .map((v) => parseInt(v as string))
        .filter((v) => !isNaN(v)) as Array<GetResultType<TEnumType>>;
    }

    throw new Error(
      `enum type "${this.enumType}" is not supported in EnumUtil.getAllValues`
    );
  }

  parse(value: GetResultType<TEnumType>) {
    //protect the input
    const allPossibelValues = this.getAllValues();

    if (!allPossibelValues.includes(value)) {
      throw new Error(
        `Cannot parse enum value "${value}". It should be one of ${allPossibelValues.join(
          ','
        )} `
      );
    }
    return value as unknown as TEnum;
  }
}
```

Comment: Useful utility! A simple change converts arrays too: `parseArray(vv: GetResultType<TEnumType>[]) { return vv.map(e=> this.parse(e) ); }` and works with `@Transform`

Answer (score -2):

If you are using namespaces to extend the functionality of your enum then you can also do something like

```
    enum Color {
        Red, Green
    }

    export namespace Color {
      export function getInstance(color: string) : Color {
        if(color == 'Red') {
          return Color.Red;
        } else if (color == 'Green') {
          return Color.Green;
        }
      }
    }
```

and use it like this

```
  Color.getInstance('Red');
```