# Typescript `enum` from JSON string

Tags: json, enums, typescript

Is there any way to have a TypeScript enum compatible with strings from JSON?

For example:

```
enum Type { NEW, OLD }

interface Thing { type: Type }

let thing:Thing = JSON.parse('{"type": "NEW"}');

alert(thing.type == Type.NEW); // false
```

I would *like* `thing.type == Type.NEW` to be true. Or more specifically, I wish I could specify the `enum` values to be defined as *strings*, not numbers.

I am aware that I can use `thing.type.toString() == Type[Type.NEW]` but this is cumbersome and seems to make the enum type annotation confusing and misleading, which defeats its purpose. The JSON is technically *not* supplying a valid enum value, so I shouldn't type the property to the enum.

So what I am currently doing instead is using a string type with static constants:

```
const Type = { NEW: "NEW", OLD: "OLD" }

interface Thing { type: string }

let thing:Thing = JSON.parse('{"type": "NEW"}');

alert(thing.type == Type.NEW); // true
```

This gets me the usage I want, but the type annotation `string` is way too broad and error prone.

I'm a bit surprised that a superset of JavaScript doesn't have string based enums. Am I missing something? Is there a different way this can be done?

---

**Update TS 1.8**

Using [string literal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#string-literal-types) is another alternative (thanks @basaret), but to get the desired enum-like usage (above) it requires defining your values *twice*: once in a string literal type, and once as a value (constant or namespace):

```
type Type = "NEW" | "OLD";
const Type = {
    NEW: "NEW" as Type,
    OLD: "OLD" as Type
}

interface Thing { type: Type }

let thing:Thing = JSON.parse(`{"type": "NEW"}`);

alert(thing.type === Type.NEW); // true
```

This works but takes a lot of boilerplate, enough that I don't use it most of the time. For now I'm hoping the [proposal for `string enums`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1206#issuecomment-240581743) will eventually make the roadmap.

---

**Update TS 2.1**

The new [`keyof` type lookup](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) allows for the string literal type to be generated from the keys of a const or namespace, which makes the definition a *little* less redundant:

```
namespace Type {
    export const OLD = "OLD";
    export const NEW = "NEW";
}
type Type = keyof typeof Type;

interface Thing { type: Type }

const thing: Thing = JSON.parse('{"type": "NEW"}');
thing.type == Type.NEW // true
```

---

**Update TS 2.4**

[TypeScript 2.4 added support for string enums](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#string-enums)! The above example becomes:

```
enum Type {
    OLD = "OLD",
    NEW = "NEW"
}

interface Thing { type: Type }
const thing: Thing = JSON.parse('{"type": "NEW"}');
alert(thing.type == Type.NEW) // true
```

This looks *nearly* perfect, but there's still some heartache:

- You *still* have to write the value twice, ie `OLD = "OLD"`, and there's no validation that you don't have a typo, like `NEW = "MEW"`... this has already bitten me in real code.
- There's some oddities (perhaps bugs?) with how the enum is type checked, its not just a string literal type shorthand, which is what would be truly correct. Some issues I've bumped into:

  ```
  enum Color { RED = "RED", BLUE = "BLUE", GREEN = "GREEN" }

  type ColorMap = { [P in Color]: number; }

  declare const color: Color;
  declare const map: ColorMap;
  map[color] // Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ColorMap' has no index signature.

  const red: Color = "RED"; // Type '"RED"' is not assignable to type 'Color'.
  const blue: Color = "BLUE" as "RED" | "BLUE" | "GREEN"; // Error: Type '"RED" | "BLUE" | "GREEN"' is not assignable to type 'Color'.
  ```

  The equivalent code with `enum Color` replaced by string literal types work fine...

Yeah, I think I have OCD about this, I just want my perfect JS enums. :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you are using Typescript before the 2.4 release, there is a way to achieve that with enums by casting the values of your enum to `any`.

An [example of your first implementation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Type%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20NEW%20%3D%20%22NEW%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OLD%20%3D%20%22OLD%22%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Thing%20%7B%20type%3A%20Type%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20thing%3AThing%20%3D%20JSON.parse('%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22NEW%22%7D')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(thing.type%20%3D%3D%20Type.NEW)%3B%20%2F%2F%20true#src=enum%20Type%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20NEW%20%3D%20%3Cany%3E%22NEW%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OLD%20%3D%20%3Cany%3E%22OLD%22%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Thing%20%7B%20type%3A%20Type%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20thing%3AThing%20%3D%20JSON.parse('%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22NEW%22%7D')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(thing.type%20%3D%3D%20Type.NEW)%3B%20%2F%2F%20true)

```
enum Type {
    NEW = <any>"NEW",
    OLD = <any>"OLD",
}

interface Thing { type: Type }

let thing:Thing = JSON.parse('{"type": "NEW"}');

alert(thing.type == Type.NEW); // true
```

[Typescript 2.4 has built in support for string enums](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/) already, so the cast to `any` would be no longer necessary and you could achieve it without the use of [`String Literal Union Type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), which is ok for validation and autocomplete, but not so good for readability and refactoring, depending on the usage scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I had known about the `any` assertion before. Now, I'm trying out TS 2.4 string enums, and it's quite close to what I originally wanted... but I've found some issues with the way TS type checks it...

Comment: @Aaron cool, glad to help! Also, you might want to check the [ts-enums](https://github.com/LMFinney/ts-enums) project as it makes enum handling very versatile and powerful for a lot of use cases

Comment: Wow, this turned out to be a lifesaver! As I [commented](/q/17380845/how-to-convert-string-to-enum-in-typescript#comment94130934_52933064) on another answer, this only works if your keys match the string values as no reverse mapping is generated for string enums. Whatsoever, casting the string values to `any` is enough for the compiler to create a reverse mapping.  It would be really helpful, if you could edit this info into your answer.

Comment: It may show warning by your linter when use `<any>"string value"` (consistent-type-assertions), the "workaround" is simply change to `"string value" as any`

Comment: Good solution.  However, I recommend using variable names unrelated to the concept in your example.  Your `type: Type` is going to confuse newbies.  Same thing with an `enum` named `Type`.  Use clearly tangential names like "foo" and "bar" or 
 at least "MyEnum".

Answer (score 5):

In case someone's still looking at this question in 2021:

> **@Aaron wrote in the original question:**
>
> This looks *nearly* perfect, but there's still some heartache:
>
> You still have to [...]
>
> ```
> enum Color { RED = "RED", BLUE = "BLUE", GREEN = "GREEN" }
>
> type ColorMap = { [P in Color]: number; }
>
> declare const color: Color;
> declare const map: ColorMap;
> map[color] // Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ColorMap' has no index signature.
> // [...]
> ```
>
> The equivalent code with enum Color replaced by string literal types work fine...
>
> Yeah, I think I have OCD about this, I just want my perfect JS enums. :)

#### 1. `keyof typeof enumObj`

Regarding,

> The equivalent code with enum Color replaced by string literal types work fine...

use the `typeof` and `keyof` operators in chained conjunction.

```
type ColorKeys = keyof typeof Color
type ColorMap = { [P in ColorKeys]: number; } // will have strongly typed keys
```

No more implicit `any` when accessing `map: ColorMap`.
This **will work with numeric enums as well** (which can (and should more often than not) be `const`).

> **From [Typescript Handbook - Enums at compile time](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-compile-time):**
>
> Even though Enums are real objects that exist at runtime, the keyof keyword works differently than you might expect for typical objects. Instead, use keyof typeof to get a Type that represents all Enum keys as strings.

#### 2. [`ts-enum-util`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-enum-util)

Check out [`ts-enum-util`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-enum-util), which offers strongly typed interfaces to (likely) all your enum-related needs.

Answer (score 3):

**TS 2.9.2** 
My solution:

```
export enum Enums { VALUE1, VALUE2 }
```

and when I have value from API json:

```
 switch (response.enumValue.toString()) { //can be without toString if we have string value from JSON.
    case Enums[Enums.VALUE1]:
      ...
    case Enums[Enums.VALUE2]:
      ...
 }
```

Comment: I mentioned this in my OP, it's not what I'm going for. Basically it means your JSON is *not* satisfying valid enum values and you need some kind of interop code (I guess what your example is showing). I want `response.enumValue == Enums.VALUE1` to be true and type compatible.

Answer (score 1):

> but the type annotation string is way too broad and error prone.

Agreed. One quick workaround (if you have the luxury of code generation you can automate this):

```
interface Thing { type: "NEW" | "OLD" }
```

These are called *string literals* in a *union*. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/stringEnums.html

Comment: This looks promising. We will investigate when we upgrade to TS 1.8. I was playing with it and wasn't able to work out how to use the string literal values as constants, ie something like `thing.type == Type.NEW`.

Comment: [This is as close as I could get](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=type%20Type%20%3D%20%22NEW%22%20%7C%20%22OLD%22%3B%0Aconst%20Type%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09NEW%3A%20%22NEW%22%2C%0A%09OLD%3A%20%22OLD%22%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Thing%20%7B%20type%3A%20Type%20%7D%0A%0Alet%20thing%3AThing%20%3D%20JSON.parse(%60%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22NEW%22%7D%60)%3B%0A%0Aalert(thing.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20Type.NEW)%3B), but it requires defining the `Type` and the values twice, once as a `type` for use as an interface type annotation, and again as a `const` for uses where I need the values. Can this be improved?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using converter functions as a stopgap. Hopefully this thread comes to a resolution: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1206

```
enum ErrorCode {
    Foo,
    Bar
}

interface Error {
    code: ErrorCode;
    message?: string;
}

function convertToError(obj: any): Error {
    let typed: Error = obj as Error;

    // Fix any enums
    typed.code = ErrorCode[typed.code.toString()];
    return typed;
}
```