# Postgres enum in TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

In TypeORM, how can I create a postgres enum type *Gender* as in this raw query

```
CREATE TYPE public.Gender AS ENUM (
    'male', 'female'
);
ALTER TABLE public.person ALTER COLUMN gender TYPE public.gender USING gender::gender;
```

and use it in the Entity class?

I have tried

```
@Entity()
export class Person {
    @Column('enum')
    gender: 'male' | 'female'
}
```

but obviously this isn't the right way, since I got the error message "type *enum* does not exist".

I don't want to use typescript enum either, since it will give me a bunch of 0s and 1s in the database.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer is still valid but a bit outdated as `0.1.0` alpha versions of TypeORM support enums for both [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/e7239cc02be65be9e60bdf2dc7d54c65f8bc254f/src/driver/types/ColumnTypes.ts#L123) and MySQL.

---

`PostgreSQL` has a built in enum type, but unfortunately `TypeORM` currently [only supports it for MySQL](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/671#issuecomment-315550091).

However, you could achieve a similar result with an int-type enum by using the `@Column` type as `int` and using the enum for your field type.

```
enum Gender {
  Male,
  Female,
  Other
}

@Entity()
export class Person {
    @Column('int')
    gender: Gender
}
```

(This approach lets you use the [`@IsEnum` decorator from class-validator](https://github.com/pleerock/class-validator#validation-decorators) to validate the input if needed)

You could also use string enums (available on TypeScript 2.4, check [Typescript `enum` from JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760096/typescript-enum-from-json-string/44906580#44906580) for older versions) and if that is the case just change the data type to `string` instead.

```
enum Gender {
  Male = 'male',
  Female = 'female',
  Other = 'other'
}

@Entity()
export class Person {
    @Column('text')
    gender: Gender
}
```

Answer (score 132):

#### Enum is now supported on TypeOrm for postgres

By the [docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#enum-column-type)

> enum column type is supported by postgres and mysql. There are various possible column definitions:
>
> Using typescript enums:

```
export enum UserRole {
    ADMIN = "admin",
    EDITOR = "editor",
    GHOST = "ghost"
}

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({
        type: "enum",
        enum: UserRole,
        default: UserRole.GHOST
    })
    role: UserRole;

}
```

> Using array with enum values:

```
export type UserRoleType = "admin" | "editor" | "ghost",

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({
        type: "enum",
        enum: ["admin", "editor", "ghost"],
        default: "ghost"
    })
    role: UserRoleType;
}
```

Comment: for the enum name in database it creates prefix with the table name. is it possible to avoid it somehow?

Comment: @kashlo Are you generating migrations automatically with the orm cli?

Answer (score 4):

As the accepted answer states, it is now supported in postgres but still buggy: [Github issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1997), the fix will be released in the next RC probably. Meanwhile, I saw on the thread a nice solution which I even liked it more than the actual feature fully working:

> fwiw I've been using string enum with check constraint. It's a lot
>   more flexible than actual postgres enum, which creates whole new data
>   types in postgres index and are really hard to manage (alter table,
>   etc.)

```
export function CheckEnum(tableName: string, fieldName: string, enumValue: any) {
  // Hash enum value and put it as part of constraint name so we can
  // force typeorm to generate migration for enum changes.
  const hash = crypto
    .createHash('sha1')
    .update(Object.values(enumValue).join(''))
    .digest('hex')
  return Check(
    // https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/8f87c65a0a-postgresqls-max-identifier-length-is-63-bytes
    `cke_${tableName}_${fieldName}_${hash}`.slice(0, 63),
    `${fieldName} in (${Object.values(enumValue).map(t => `'${t}'`)})`,
  )
}
```

> And use it like so

```
export enum Gender {
  Male = 'male',
  Female = 'female',
  Other = 'other'
}

@Entity()
@CheckEnum('person', 'gender', Gender)
export class Person {
```

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres, the column type should be 'text', not 'string', as string results in
DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "string" in "" is not supported by "postgres" database.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that using the same enum in multiple entities might result in strange enum missing properties errors. It took me hours to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See @noam steiner's answer but TypeORM will recognize the enum type without providing it explicitly, so this is enough:

```ss
enum SomeEnum{
  # ...
}

class Entity {
  @Field()
  @Column()
  someEnumField: SomeEnum;
}
```