# Cannot set values on uuid or enum fields in Postgres using TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I've been stuck on this for a good hour, and unfortunately can't find anything relevant in the docs.

I'm unable to set values on fields that use types like `enum` or `uuid`. For instance:

```
export enum PhotoStatus {
  WORKING = 'WORKING',
  DONE = 'DONE'
}

export class Photo {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number:
  
  @Column()
  size: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: PhotoStatus,
    default: PhotoStatus.WORKING,
  })
  status: PhotoStatus;
}
```

But when I try to create a new record, like so:

```
  const photo = new Photo();
  photo.size = 'huge';
  photo.status = PhotoStatus.DONE;
  await connection.manager.save(photo);
```

It throws an error:

```
BadRequestException: ERROR: column "status" is of type content_status_enum but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

This happens for uuid columns too.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45153609/460557

Comment: @JorgeCampos Unfortunately not. I don't want a text field, I want an actual enum in the DB.

Comment: I mean his first suggestion in the answer. marking it as `int` and using the IsEnum decorator?

Comment: I'd rather avoid using `int` if possible, as values like `7` or `3` in the database don't really indicate what the value means. This is why I'd prefer to use an `enum` type.

Comment: Problem is right now there is no way around it since typeorm doesn't support postgresql enums. Either you change the database or your code to workaround it. As it is mentioned in this [github issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/671#issuecomment-315550091)

Comment: That was 2017. It's now supported. https://typeorm.io/#/entities/enum-column-type

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem? Running into the same thing

Comment: Sorry, I abandoned TypeORM so I never circled back to this issue.