# How to handle reverse mapping of string enums with different string literals in typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums

There have been some similar questions, like:

- [Reverse-Mapping for String Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883072/reverse-mapping-for-string-enums)
- [Typescript `enum` from JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760096/typescript-enum-from-json-string/44906580#44906580).

My example is different from the other linked questions because I am using a string literal which is different from the enum member name.

I have the following enum:

```
export enum AttackType {
  MELEE = <any>'close', // I had to use <any> to make it work at all
  RANGED = <any>'far'
}
```

I want to get the correct enum based on the assigned string literal.
I thought `AttackType['close']` would be the same as `AttackType.MELEE`, but it is not. The former prints `MELEE`, and the latter prints `close`, making the following statement false

`AttackType['close']===AttackType.MELEE`

So If I have the following class:

```
export class Hero{
 attackType: AttackType;
 constructor(){
  this.attackType = AttackType['close']; // no errors, and prints MELEE,
  this.attackType = AttackType.MELEE; // no errors, and prints close,
  this.attackType = AttackType[AttackType['close']]; // compile error.
  this.attackType = AttackType[<string>AttackType['close']]; // no errors, and prints close.

 }
}
```

I am wondering how I should tackle this problem. How can I make sure that the `attackType` is assigned properly when I only know the string literal (e.g. 'close')?

I could use the "strange" way (`AttackType[<string>AttackType['close']]`) to assign the correct enum value, making it be the same as `AttackType.MELEE`, but I am not sure if this a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not happy about the idea of trying to fool the compiler into generating [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) for string enums by using that `<any>` type assertion.   The reverse string mappings are omitted on purpose, as [@RyanCavanaugh](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh) said in a [relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21935#issuecomment-371583528):

> If we provided the reverse map automatically (which, by the way, is not necessarily non-ambiguous!), then you'd have no way to distinguish keys from values unless there was a completely separate object created at runtime. It is trivial to write a function that constructs the reverse map if you want it; our goal is to emit as little code as possible so it makes sense to just emit the data you need (to keep code size down) and let you construct the reverse map on an as-needed basis.

I think if you continue using that trick, you will find yourself needing to do assertions like you're doing, and you shouldn't be surprised if some future version of TypeScript breaks it entirely.

But if a development lead for TypeScript says "it is trivial to write a function that constructs the reverse map", then we can try that and see how it goes.  So how would you go about that?   At runtime you really just have to iterate through the enum object entries and produce a new object with the keys and values switched.  And if you want both the forward and reverse map in the same object, you can [merge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) the properties from the regular enum into the reversed one:

```
type Entries<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T]

function reverseEnum<E extends Record<keyof E, string | number>>(
  e: E
): { [K in E[keyof E]]: Extract<Entries<E>, [any, K]>[0] };
function reverseEnum(
  e: Record<string | number, string | number>
): Record<string | number, string | number> {
  const ret: Record<string | number, string | number> = {};
  Object.keys(e).forEach(k => ret[e[k]] = k);
  return ret;
}

function twoWayEnum<E extends Record<keyof E, string | number>>(e: E) {
  return Object.assign(reverseEnum(e), e);
}
```

The signature for `reverseEnum()` involves a bit of type juggling.  The type function `Entries<T>` turns an object type `T` into a union of key value pairs., e.g., `Entries<{a: string, b: number}>` evaluates to `["a",string] | ["b",number]`.  Then the return type of `reverseEnum()` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) whose keys come from the enum *values*, and whose values come from the key for corresponding entry by [extracting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types) it.  Let's see if it works:

```
enum AttackType {
  MELEE = 'close',
  RANGED = 'far'
}

const TwoWayAttackType = twoWayEnum(AttackType);
// const TwoWayAttackType = {
//   close: "MELEE";
//   far: "RANGED";
// } & typeof AttackType

// might as well make a type called TwoWayAttackType also, 
// corresponding to the property values of the TwoWayAttackType object
type TwoWayAttackType = AttackType | keyof typeof AttackType

console.log(TwoWayAttackType.close); // "MELEE"
console.log(TwoWayAttackType[TwoWayAttackType.far]) // "far"
```

You can see that the value `TwoWayAttackType` has the same type as the `AttackType` enum constant, with extra properties `{close: "MELEE", far: "RANGED"}`.  One wrinkle is that TypeScript does not automatically generate a type named `TwoWayAttackType` corresponding to the property types of the `TwoWayAttackType` constant, so if you want one we have to make it manually, as I've done above.

Now you should be able to make your class as desired with no type errors:

```
class Hero {
  attackType: TwoWayAttackType;
  constructor() {
    this.attackType = TwoWayAttackType['close']; 
    this.attackType = TwoWayAttackType.MELEE; 
    this.attackType = TwoWayAttackType[TwoWayAttackType['close']]; 
  }
}
```

Note that if this method works for you, you can always rename the values/types above so that what I'm calling `TwoWayAttackType` is just `AttackType` (and then perhaps what I'm calling `AttackType` would be something like `OneWayAttackType` or `BaseAttackType`).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATgSwgZwDwBUoQB7ARwAmaUA9gEYBWEAxsAHxQC8UA3lANoDSUycKAGsIIcgDMoWALoAubjwA0U3tOlQAvlxFjJMgFD7xAVzgNk5QYggA3CIjQR4xgLYYYuAkVJQASvXJEYgwdCVhlNCQBAHMoAB8oOFdKe0ZGAAp9KGzceRh9AEp5Tl5+QRhtUTCYNTyCRABDBncEFHR3RmUuBrgQZR5pRi4ABnUNAG4jU3NLKGs7Byckl0yc3L8AoIxIlDhYhOWUxAiovfjE5NTC+X86QOCdmPPD+xPd-YuXI+Z2LJy7uCROYQYA3TYPU4fF7HKCPM4HS6IZhsdgTP7ZADyNHowAAdDo0OkIAVceJAjAmgALdJCVjMazALgQbRqVjCAqTNYM4yIKwgyYaQwmMzACyCYAAd3IAHUGiBnG4PPhCCQyLd7iEqpIYG8ngivqkMhA8gUOOjgcAeYIsbQGLiGmg0MhonB0vN7I4FUSCspiQLDERXFAAILAYBNIRYcDQX5rACyMAAMjAPGwAOR0AA25EcacU5t8wYAcgBxGAAETZafEDUQaf0gv0AKBWClspAofDdEj0bZkplcq9nYjUcgHP0AHoJ1Bm8ApG25cPu6PoCjJ9Pslmc8aoAAiBPJmC7yZTnI1xDyXeF0sV4-rzRQABkUFAkDCS57kEMp5czspc4dKAJQgTNMygFwGhEKAGhfXs6AaUCIGIecBw7MMR17BC0HIZR7zuRBrDQMBLGIJ5gHIF9KWgMBEHISBEFAKAbAQ4x0AoSRgColD2w-FcKGxBh9FfaBW1Q3jezYcTIHOUIOOjd90OXaNDGbchMwgXFs2idJRJ4xTPw0rdHA5KBT33JMU13JtLGw9TNPIbTdMXfSVy4Jy0K7AzSVraRTTM89dyAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After reading this I figured that omitting ‘<any>’ and creating a simple function to set the desired enum value based on a string input is a better Idea. Thank you for the example as well.