# why I can't get the string from enum value in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

sorry I am newbie in Typescript.

I have enum with String value like this

```
export enum NotificationType {
    GeneralInfo = "General Info",
    EventUpdate = "Event Update",
}
```

and I want to get that string value in a method. I have tried it like this

```
notifictionTypeToString(type: NotificationType) : string {
    
    if (type == NotificationType.EventUpdate) {
        return NotificationType[NotificationType.EventUpdate];
    } 
}
```

if I read the [documentation about enum reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) , I can access the string value like that, but I have an error

[image]

so how to get string value in enum ?

Comment: The documentation says "In addition to creating an object with property names for members, **numeric** enums members also get a reverse mapping from enum values to enum names."  You have a string enum, not a numeric enums.  String enums do not get such reverse mappings; you'll have to do it [yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039138/how-to-handle-reverse-mapping-of-string-enums-with-different-string-literals-in).  See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54041614/2887218) to the question this duplicates; if I use that code here, it gives you [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO8RrN).