# Enum in Json in Typescript with Interface?

Tags: json, typescript, enums

I have a json file which looks like these:

```
{ 
     "ui": "Header"
}
```

while "ui" is an enum.
I load this part with JSON.Parse in my typescript webpack envoriment with node.js and ts-loader, so my error is:

**"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UiDescriptionTypeEnum'."**

and my interface I am trying to cast into is:

```
interface UI
{
     ui: UiDescriptionTypeEnum
}
```

while having the enum like this:

```
enum UiDescriptionTypeEnum
{
     Header = "Header"
}
```

Here is a working typescript play with the error:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXBAsAKAN7qjqAJYAQwBNgAnKAXigCICTyb0BfddASxABdyAzQgMbBYcAJLc+g4eixpcUHgGcuALhFJILNmgBuhCgCtFAexBUoGBcGVqA5PVJlbUVmnQAbYFyiE18cTxk-ELmRqYA3EA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to enum in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: Thank you, it did not. I read into it, but my main problem seems the json converter here, not typescript itself

Comment: is it a case issue like Caroline pointed out?

Comment: AI allready answered that: no it isnt.

Comment: missed that, sorry. check out this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760096/typescript-enum-from-json-string 
Enum in Json in Typescript with Interface?

Comment: I read this 10 times, but as I understand my syntax would be completly fine

Comment: @rmjoia added a playground linkl

Comment: I replaced your line 13 with `let a: MyInterface = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))` and it works.. `[LOG]: {
  "test": "Header"
} `

Comment: btw.. `let a: MyInterface = json as MyInterface` also works

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXBAsAKAN7qjqAJYAQwBNgAnKAXigCICTyb0BfddASxABdyAzQgMbBYcAJLc+g4eixpcUHgGcuALhFJILNmgBuhCgCtFAexBUoGBcGVqA5PVJlbUVmnQAbYFyiE18cTxk-ELmlkqqUPZEjs7MPooiAZJC2p7eAEZ+YhJBUuZGpvGJOcHA2gKmJp4AdO7GAOYAFIQAlOgVIFXAtQ2N6S1AA

Comment: Well it works fine for me too, but why I have to convert it?

Comment: I suppose that, if you don't parse the json, it's just an object, and Typescript infers it as an object, on the other example, you cast that object to your type, and then Typescript knows what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in the enum are case sensitive

try to redefine the enum as below

```
enum UiDescriptionTypeEnum
{
     header = "header"
}
```

Updated the example from the link

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Header = "Header"
}

interface MyInterface 
{
    test: MyEnum
}

var json = { test: 'Header' }
var jsonObj = {test: MyEnum.Header} // option 1:  to define the type from Enum

let a : MyInterface =  json as MyInterface; // option 2: cast js object to your interface ( a more likely scenario)
```

Comment: Thank you, did not solve my problem, I just had a typo in my question, the "Header"  was upper case in my json allready, so they matched