# Typescript, enums and string

Tags: string, typescript, enums

I have a hard time converting a string coming from the env variable to enum.

Here's the enum:

```
enum Environment {
    Test = 1,
    Development,
    Production
}

export default Environment;
```

And here's what I've been trying:

```
export default class GlobalParameters {
    public static Env: Environment = Environment[<string>process.env.NODE_ENV];
}
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) // Gives "Development"
let str = String(process.env.NODE_ENV); // Gives "Development"
console.log(Environment[str])  //Gives undefined
Object.seal(GlobalParameters);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to enum in TypeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-to-convert-string-to-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: @martin I'm using this method - creating a string from the env var, however I still get undefined when I try to retrieve an enum

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine:

```
enum Environment {
    Test = 1,
    Development,
    Production
}

console.log(Environment[2]) // "Development"
let str = String(Environment[2]);
console.log(str); // "Development"
console.log(Environment[str]) // 2
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Environment%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Test%20%3D%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Development%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Production%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(Environment%5B2%5D)%20%2F%2F%20%22Development%22%0Alet%20str%20%3D%20String(Environment%5B2%5D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(str)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22Development%22%0Aconsole.log(Environment%5Bstr%5D)%20%2F%2F%202))

Comment: Yes, when I change

`let str: string = String(process.env.NODE_ENV);`
to
`let str: string = String("Development");`

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, when I was defining the environment variable in the command line it must have added some whitespace characters, because when I changed retrieving string to

```
let str: string = String(process.env.NODE_ENV).replace(" ", "");
```

It works fine.