# Typed enum instance in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I have the following method which transforms a string instance of an enum to the corresponding enum member on an object:

```
function transformEnum<TBase>(base: TBase, member: keyof TBase, enumInstance: any) {
    base[member] = enumInstance[base[member]];
}
```

It's called like this:

```
transformEnum(result, "day", DayOfWeek);
```

Is there any way to type the `enumInstance` variable? The typing doesn't have to be perfect, but constraining it at least somewhat would be nice.

Alternatively I've tried

```
function transform<T>(get: () => T, set: (x: T) => void, enumInstance: T) {
    set((enumInstance as any)[get()]);
}
```

But when I call this like so:

```
transform<DayOfWeek>(() => result.day, (x) => { result.day = x; }, DayOfWeek);
```

I get

> [ts] Argument of type 'typeof DayOfWeek' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DayOfWeek'.

Comment: Please check if this works for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-to-convert-string-to-enum-in-typescript

Comment: @BalajiV if you read my code sample you'll see that that's what I'm doing. The question isn't how to do the conversion but how to type the function parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function transform<T, TKey extends keyof T>(get: () => TKey, set: (x: T[TKey]) => void, enumInstance: T) {
  set(enumInstance[get()]);
}
```

Example:

```
enum DayOfWeek {
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, ...
}

type DayOfWeekKey = keyof typeof DayOfWeek;

class ClassWithDay {
  day: DayOfWeekKey | DayOfWeek;
}

let c = new ClassWithDay();
c.day = "Monday";
transform(() => c.day as DayOfWeekKey, v => {c.day = v;}, DayOfWeek);
// c.day is now 0
```