# Typescript function to convert string enum member to enum

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I'd like to write something like this in Typescript:

```
export function stringToEnum<T>(enumObj: T, str: string): keyof T {
    return enumObj[str];
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
enum MyEnum {
  Foo
}

stringToEnum<MyEnum>(MyEnum, 'Foo');
```

where it would return

`MyEnum.Foo`

The function above works as expected... but the typings are throwing errors.  For the parameter `MyEnum` in `stringToEnum<MyEnum>(MyEnum, 'Foo');`, Typescript complains tha:

> Argument of type 'typeof MyEnum' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'MyEnum'

which makes sense... unfortunately.  Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Comment: Why? Whats your usecase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it all natively without having to write a function:

```
enum Color {
    red,
    green,
    blue
}

// Enum to string
const redString: string = Color[Color.red];
alert(redString);

// String to enum
const str = 'red';
const redEnum: Color = Color[str];
alert(redEnum);
```

Or you can have some fun with it...

```
enum MyEnum {
  Foo,
  Bar
}

function stringToEnum<ET, T>(enumObj: ET, str: keyof ET): T{
    return enumObj[<string>str];
}

const val = stringToEnum<typeof MyEnum, MyEnum>(MyEnum, 'Foo');

// Detects that `foo` is a typo
const val2 = stringToEnum<typeof MyEnum, MyEnum>(MyEnum, 'foo');
```

Comment: Right.  Is there any way to do it with a method, though?

Comment: I've added an example for fun... the call to the function is significantly trickier than just using `MyEnum['Foo']`.

Comment: Hey @Fenton. TS compiler errors out with 7053 in current TS versions, also within your function. [This](https://blog.oio.de/2014/02/28/typescript-accessing-enum-values-via-a-string/) explains it. So the easiest solution would be: `const str: string = 'red'; const redEnum: Color = (<any>Color)[str];`

Comment: In addition to my last comment: If you got an enum like `enum Color { Red = "red"}` then `const redEnum: Color = (<any>Color)["red"]` won't match as the indexer matches the enum-member-name. So only `const redEnum: Color = (<any>Color)["Red"]` would work.

Answer (score 3):

Your signature is a bit mixed up. The return type should be `T[keyof T]` if you intend for the method to return an enum value. The type of the `str` param should also be `keyof T` to prevent you from passing invalid strings in, but this will limit you to passing string literals in (or well-typed variables of type `keyof T`, but not `string`):

```
function stringToEnum<T>(enumObj: T, str: keyof T): T[keyof T]
```

Then either don't specify the type param and let the compiler infer the type correctly:

```
// type: Foo
// value: 0  
const result = stringToEnum(MyEnum, 'Foo');
```

Or you need to provide `typeof MyEnum` as the type param:

```
// type: Foo
// value: 0  
const result = stringToEnum<typeof MyEnum>(MyEnum, 'Foo');
```

If you really want to be able to pass in any arbitrary string enum name, then the return type is a lie: should be `T[keyof T] | undefined`. You'll also run into trouble when attempting `enumObj[str]` if the type of `str` is `string` and you have `noImplicitAny` compiler option enabled.

There's a bit more to making generic functions that work with enum types properly, especially numeric enums that have reverse lookup entries at run-time. Take a look at the source code for `ts-enum-util` ([github](https://github.com/UselessPickles/ts-enum-util), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-enum-util)) for inspiration

Answer (score 1):

```
 stringToEnum(MyEnum, 'Foo');
```

Just leave away the generic and let typescript do that.
Thats because the type stored under MyEnum does not match the Enum itself but is a union type of its values:

```
 enum Test { A, B };

 const value: Test /* "A" | "B" */ = Test.A;
```