# how to convert a string value to enum in typescript

Tags: typescript

here's my enum definition

```
export enum CallerComponent {
  HOMEPAGE= 'homepage',
  DEFAULT = 'default'
}

 callerString = 'homepage';
 const caller: CallerComponent  = CallerComponent[callerString] //I'm getting undefined...
```

All the page I've found say this is the way to go. Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something similar to this:

```
const callerString: string = "homepage";
Object.keys(CallerComponent).forEach((key) => {
    const component: CallerComponent = CallerComponent[key as keyof typeof CallerComponent]
    console.log(component);
});
```

**EDIT:** A google search resulted in the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript) being answered( with a similar solution too)

Comment: I had to add a check for the key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`CallerComponent` compiles to the dictionary like `{HOMEPAGE: "homepage", DEFAULT: "default"}`. What is why  CallerComponent["homepage"] is `undefined`.

And `"homepage"  === CallerComponent.HOMEPAGE`.

So,  I 'm confused. What do you want to achieve?

UPD: Ah, I get it. I  guess you tried to get a key name by the value? It works this way with regular enums, not string ones.

```
    export enum CallerComponent {
       HOMEPAGE,
       DEFAULT
    }


    const keyName = CallerComponent[CallerComponent.HOMEPAGE]; // HOMEPAGE
```

More information is here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings

> Keep in mind that string enum members do not get a reverse mapping generated at all.

So if you *really* would like to reverse it by some reasons, you could play around the underlying dictionary, as you usually do in plain javascript