# Can I validate that a value is within the enum conditions with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have:

```
export enum SiteCodes {
    'USA',
    'CAN',
    'GB'
}

export interface GetSkuItemsRequest {
    siteCode: SiteCodes;
}


export default class GetSkuItems {
    public event: APIGatewayProxyEvent;
    private PARAMS_TO_PICK = [
        'siteCode'
    ];

    private validateParams(pickedParams: { [key: string]: string }){
        const {
            siteCode
        } = pickedParams;

        if (!siteCode) {
            throw MISSING_PARAMS_ERROR;
        }

    }
}
```

What I want to do in the `validateParams` is to ensure that the `siteCode` in included in the enum of `SiteCodes`

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can index into an `enum` with a string, my first pass at it was that you can verify it like this:

```
const isValid = SiteCodes[siteCode as any] !== undefined;
```

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgF2AYQPYBNgGcoG8BQURUA5AKowCCJANIcScpQHK31EkDiAQifgL758AMzAgAxgjioQUcQAtg4gNYAKEAEMIwAFxQsCAE5wQAcwCUeeuJkGocLADUNAGzjooAXliIUGbADamtpQGjgaIACeALpQAISe3mKYwibA6ADc1raoLsAAdC6opqoABgAkuMHA-HqVDs5u6Pyl5lmC+ApKagBEFD1tRAD0Q1AgqAhQAG6u7p2KKqp9VAMZUCPTs+hAA)

There are a couple of problems with the above, though:

1. It'll accept `0`, `1`, `2`, `"0"`, `"1"`, and `"2"` as well as valid enum strings.
2. It'll accept `"valueOf"`, `"toString"`, and other `Object.prototype` properties as valid enum strings.

So here's a more thorough version:

```
const isValid = !!(siteCode && isNaN(+siteCode) && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(SiteCodes, siteCode));
```

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgF2AYQPYBNgGcoG8BQURUA5AKowCCJANIcScpQHK31EkDiAQifgL758AMzAgAxgjioQUcQAtg4gNYAKLIhQZgALihYEAJzggA5gEo89cTINQ4WAGoBDADZx0UALxQAhL-VNNEwoADJQ+yxmZ2ZVAGoNJGDgS3CoAHkAIwArJQQAOgAHQ1QEUoBPQuB8+WcsdIB3EAAFEqrDBHL88TdXVXgk7SwafSDtc3MAbmtbVFdq11RTVQADABJcRK1Mfj0Nhxd3dH4VqYEhBSU1ACIKa6miAHpHqBBSqAA3Nw98S5VVW5Ue6TKDPT7fdC-RT-a4ABmBxDBbwQ4KOQA)

Comment: Thank you so much - so easy!

Comment: @Shamoon - Note: The first version of my answer would also accept `siteCode` being `0`, `1`, `2`, `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, `"valueOf"`, and a few others as valid enum strings. I've updated with a more thorough version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'in' like:

```
enum SiteCodes {
    'USA',
    'CAN',
    'GB'
}

let badSiteCode = 'badSiteCode';
let validSiteCode = 'USA'

console.log(badSiteCode in SiteCodes);
console.log(validSiteCode in SiteCodes);
```

Checkout this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dqLatzk2/

Comment: The only problem with this is that if you set `badSiteCode` to `0`, `1`, or `3`, you'll get a false positive, since the objects have properties both for the number version and the string version. ... ... ... which is also a problem with *my* answer. :-)

Comment: Both of ours *also* accept `"valueOf"`  and other `Object.prototype` properties.