# convert string to enum Value in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

i need to pass `enum type` to server . but when i send the form to server it send `enum fild` by type `string` .

this is my enum :

```
export enum PayTypes {
  Free,
  Subscribe
}
```

and this is my form :

```
createForm(): void {
    this.lessonAddForm = new FormGroup({
        payType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
}


addLesson(): void {
    const payString = PayTypes[this.lessonAddForm.controls['payType'].value];
    const payType: PayTypes = PayTypes[payString];
    this.lessonAdd = this.lessonAddForm.value;
    this.lessonAdd.payType = payType;
    this.subscriptions = this.lessonService
        .add(this.lessonAdd)
        .subscribe(
            res => {
                if (res.success === true) {
                    this.alertService.success('', 'GENERAL.ADD_SUCCESS');
                    this.backToMenu();
                }
            }
        );
}
```

and i try for convert string to enum by this way :

```
    const payString = PayTypes[this.lessonAddForm.controls['payType'].value];
    const payType: PayTypes = PayTypes[payString];
    this.lessonAdd = this.lessonAddForm.value;
    this.lessonAdd.payType = payType;
```

but it not work .

**How can i solve this Problem????**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to enum in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must convert the value inside the square bracket to string like this

```
const payType: PayTypes = PayTypes[payString.toString()];
```

Also you can view this [post](https://blog.oio.de/2014/02/28/typescript-accessing-enum-values-via-a-string/)

Update: Check how you get payString data does it match with your enum definition ? Please note your payString data have to be the same with your enum key

For example:

```
PayTypes['Free'] // This will work
```

And

```
PayTypes['free'] // This won't
```

Comment: still send it `string`

Comment: @kianoushdortaj working fine [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqgzeq)!

Comment: @kianoushdortaj check my answer again