# How to type an array of strings that contain one or more of a collection of strings?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following roles for authorization:

```js
['admin', 'manager', 'user']
```

How can I make a type, lets call it `Roles` that is a string array ( `string[]` ) that can only contain items from the list of roles above? Also, it can be an empty array of strings.

**Edit:** This is my best attempt at this:

```js
type Roles = [] | ['user'] | ['manager'] | ['admin'] | ['user', 'manager'] | ['user', 'admin'] | ['manager', 'admin'] | ['user', 'manager', 'admin']
```

but it doesn't allow for:

```js
const roles:Roles = ['admin','user']
```

Also, this would become really unwieldy if I have 4 roles (the amount of options become `n!` and as above doesn't support different positions in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to define a type Role which accepts 'user' or 'admin' or 'manager' like below:

```
type Role = 'user' | 'admin' | 'manager';
type Roles = Set<Role>;
//Here 'admin' role may be duplicated but Set removes the admin of last index
//making adminUser unique set of roles
const adminUser: Roles = new Set<Role>(['user', 'manager', 'admin', 'admin']);
```

Then create another type which is a Set of type Role.

Comment: This is a pretty good solution and enough for what I need.A perfect solution for me would be an array of `Roles` where you could not have a role more than once. For example: `const wrong:Roles = ['admin','admin']` would be incorrect. Any chance you know how to make that happen? Also, I noticed you had another account and answered with it but deleted that answer. it has more rep points though. Did you want me to accept that answer instead to keep its momentum going?

Comment: @aarona In that case you can just use a set, sematically I don't think array is correct for this.

Comment: @aarona, I have update the answer and as per your requirement I have used Set instead of normal array in case of duplication. Hope, it fulfills your requirement and yeah if you want to accept the answer you can go for this account rather than deleted one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a enum with the possible values and add conversion between `string` and your custom enum.

Example:

```js
enum Role {
    Admin = 'admin',
    Manager = 'manager',
    User = 'user',
}
type Roles = Role[]

const roles: Roles = [Role.Admin, Role.User]
```

and conversion: (see [How do I convert a string to enum in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript) for details)

```js
function toRole(name: string): Role {
    return name as keyof typeof Role
}

const rolesConverted: Roles = [toRole('admin'), toRole('user')]
const roleName = Role[Role.Admin] // 'admin'
```

See TypeScript docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums
for details

Comment: Can you provide an example in your answer?