# How can I convert a string to enum sum type?

Tags: typescript, enums

This question may seem similar to [the one about converting strings to enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript), but my situation is a bit more complicated. I have two different enums and another sum type over them:

```
enum InteractiveStep {
    Pick = 'PICK',
    Ban = 'BAN'
}

enum AutoStep {
    RandomPick = 'RANDOM_PICK',
    LastPick = 'LAST_PICK'
}

type ActionStep = InteractiveStep | AutoStep
```

How can I check whether an arbitrary string is contained in the `ActionStep` type, and safely convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Using [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17592#issuecomment-449440944), I was able to come up with this:

```
enum InteractiveStep {
    Pick = 'PICK',
    Ban = 'BAN'
}

enum AutoStep {
    RandomPick = 'RANDOM_PICK',
    LastPick = 'LAST_PICK'
}

type ActionStep = InteractiveStep | AutoStep
const ActionStep = {...InteractiveStep, ...AutoStep}

const inputString: string = 'RANDOM_PICK'

const inputStep: ActionStep = ActionStep[inputString as keyof typeof ActionStep];
```