# How to convert runtime string to string enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a typescript enum `myEnum` (with string values) and a function `foo` returning a string.
I need to convert return value of `foo` to `myEnum` and default on some value if key is not present in enum.

Let's condider this piece of code:

```
enum  myEnum {
    none = "none",
    a = "a",
    b = "b"
}

function foo(): string {
    return "random-string";
}

function bar(): myEnum {
    const t = foo();
    if(t in myEnum) {
        return myEnum[t];
    }
    return myEnum.none;
}

console.log(bar());
```

That fails with typescript 4.1.2 with error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index > type 'typeof myEnum'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof myEnum'

How should I do that without losing typesafety ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to enum in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: not exactly. Answer below is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` is a `string`, in no-way related to the set of values in your `enum`.

Inherently you need to lose some type-safety, because the string could be any value. As such, you must cast it to a `myEnum` key for the win:

```
const t = foo() as keyof typeof myEnum;
```

Comment: great ! Typescript has quite evolved since version 0.8 apparently :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to suppress this warning using type guard

```
enum  myEnum {
    none = "none",
    a = "a",
    b = "b"
}

function foo(): string {
    return "random-string";
}

function isMyEnum(s: string): s is myEnum {
    return s in myEnum;
}

function bar(): myEnum {
    const t = foo();
    if(isMyEnum(t)) {
        return myEnum[t];
    }
    return myEnum.none;
}

console.log(bar());
```