# Convert number to enum

Tags: typescript

```
enum SomeEnum {
  a = 10
  b = 20
}

const n: number = 20;

const enumValue: SomeEnum = ???;
```

Is there a way to convert `n` to `enumValue` without having to write a switch-case for every enum-type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to enum in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

```js
enum SomeEnum {
  a = 10,
  b = 20
}

const n: number = 20;

const enumValue: SomeEnum = 20; // ok

const enumValue: SomeEnum = 21; // ok, please keep in mind it is unsafe
```

I encourage you to not do it.

---

Like @Beraliv mentioned in their comment, since TS 5.0 [All enums Are Union enums](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#all-enums-are-union-enums), there is an error if you want to assign invalid number:

```js
const enumValue: SomeEnum = 21;
```

If you can't switch to the newest version of TypeScript, you can check my article about [safer enums](https://catchts.com/safe-enums) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591789/enum-typescript-return-specific-value/70592714#70592714)

Comment: You can also validate the number by indexing it through the enum type twice: `const enumValue: SomeEnum | undefined = SomeEnum[SomeEnum[n] as keyof typeof SomeEnum]`

Comment: @E_net4theflagger nice approach!

Comment: It's no longer possible to assign it in TypeScript 5.0 (which is in beta now) – https://tsplay.dev/Wzaz4m