# enum typescript return specific value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an enum like this:

```
enum Test {
   'type1',
   'type2',
   'type3',
   'type4',
   'type5'
}

function getType(num: number) {

}
```

what I want is if `num = 1`, return `type1`, if `num = 2`, return `type2`, if `num >= 5`, return `type5`.

How can I do this in `getType` ?

Comment: What if `num` is `0`? What if `num` is `1.2`?

Comment: @Lesiak If you return `Test[0]` inside of `getType`, it will actually return the first element in the enum, `1.2` however will return `undefined`. Using `number` needs additional protection to ensure a valid enum member is returned.

Comment: @MikeS. I'm afraid that these are only assumptions on how the function should behave. I never said I am going to use indexer when implementing `getType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript enums are accessible though there number index on runtime, so

```
return Test[1];
```

Will return index `1` from the `Test` enum.

---

Since you want `1` to return `type1`, we'll need to subtract 1 from your `num` to get the desired index:

```js
enum Test {
   'type1',
   'type2',
   'type3',
   'type4',
   'type5'
}

function getType(num: number) {
    return Test[num - 1];
}   

console.log(getType(1));
```

Will output:

```
type1
```

---

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NCoMwEITP3afYWwy0hfTnUl/Dm3hpWEWwG0k2hyI@e0xbKrkMHzPwjbxnCtaPs6REHF/YUBBcABGV5M2o486Xgq8F3wq@K1gB@shWRsc4kDS5rbL5gTme5PXPjp4kev7@tZ/jE5quhvUAYB0HN9F5ckP1Fxita4CUNg)

Comment: But here return type is string not `Test`

Comment: Yeap, but if number is more or equal to 5, it should return `type5`. I guess, I should be doing if(num >= 5) return Test[5] ?

Comment: You could do something like `return Test[num - 1] || Test[4]` to ensure it exist. Please see this in action using [this online demo](https://tio.run/##K6ksSC1OLsosKPn/PzWvNFchJLW4RKGaS0FBQb0EKGeorgNnGyGxjZHYJkhsU3WuWi6utNK85JLM/DyF9NSSEKCoBtBkKwUgkZRapAkxXaEotaS0KA9sXzTIYl0Fw1iFmhqIgEmsNVctJxdXcn5ecX5Oql5OfroGzCxDTU1rrBKWIIn//wE).

Answer (score 5):

This is tricky question. Please see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268023/how-to-type-function-taking-an-enum#answer-69465829) question and my [article](https://catchts.com/safe-enums).

Runtime representation of enum is bidirectional object.

```js
const Test = {
  0: "type1",
  1: "type2",
  2: "type3",
  3: "type4",
  4: "type5",
  type1: 0,
  type2: 1,
  type3: 2,
  type4: 3,
  type5: 4,
}
```

Please keep this in mind during reading.

COnsider this example:

```js
enum MyEnum {
  ONE, // 0
  TWO // 1
}

// This utility type reverses object. 
// All keys become values an all values become keys
type ReverseObj<T extends Record<string, string | number>> = {
  [Prop in keyof T as T[Prop]]: Prop
}

{
  type _ = ReverseObj<{ age: 42 }> // { 42: "age" }
}

// Type representation of runtime enum value
// Please keep in mind that enum runtime value is bidirectional
// this is why I have used ReverseObject
type EnumToObj = Pick<
  {
    [Prop in keyof typeof MyEnum]: `${typeof MyEnum[Prop]}`
  }, keyof typeof MyEnum
>

type IsKeyValid<
  InitialValue extends number,
  > =
  `${InitialValue}` extends keyof ReverseObj<EnumToObj>
  ? InitialValue
  : never

{
  type _ = IsKeyValid<1> // 1
  type __ = IsKeyValid<2> // never
}

function handleEnum<
  Index extends number,
  >(index: IsKeyValid<Index>): `${Index}` extends keyof ReverseObj<EnumToObj> ? ReverseObj<EnumToObj>[`${Index}`] : never
function handleEnum<
  Index extends number,
  >(index: IsKeyValid<Index>) {
  return MyEnum[index]
}

handleEnum(0) // "ONE"
handleEnum(1) // "TWO"
handleEnum(2) // expected error
handleEnum('ONE') // expected error
handleEnum(0.1) // expected error
handleEnum(NaN) // expected error
handleEnum(Infinity) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoJPjm)

Some explanation you will find in comments. The goal is to make illegal state unrepresentable.

`IsKeyValid` - assures that you are not allowed to provide keys which are not exists in enum. For instance, you are not allowed to call `handleEnum(10)` because we have only two keys, hence allowed keys are `0 | 1`. As for the return value, I have obtained it from reversed object `ReverseObj`.

Some thing you should be aware of:

1. Types `typeof MyEnum` and `MyEnum` are not equal.
2. More explanation about using `as` in `[Prop in keyof T as T[Prop]]: Prop` you can find [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)
3. It worth using simple tuple instead of enum if you don't use custom initial indexes for enum.
   COnsider this example:

```js
const TUPLE = ['one', 'two', 'three'] as const;

type Tuple = typeof TUPLE

type AllowedIndex<Index extends number> = `${Index}` extends Exclude<keyof Tuple, keyof ReadonlyArray<any>> ? Index : never

const getter = <Index extends number>(index: AllowedIndex<Index>) =>
  TUPLE[index]

getter(1) // ok, returns "two"
getter(23) // expected error
```

4. In most cases there is even better to use immutable object instead of enum.

```js
const FakeEnum = {
  a: 0,
  b: 1
} as const
```

It is easy to work with `FakeEnum` object. Because you can easily, without any tricks obtain keys and appropertiate values of object.

IMHO, I don't think that `enum` is the best option to use in this case

P.S. If you don't like zero based index in enums, you can set your initial value:

```js
enum MyEnum {
  ONE = 1, // 1
  TWO // 2
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Above approach has his own drawbacks. As you might have noticed, all utility types are binded with `MyEnum`. They are not generic. If you are interested in generic solution where you can pass any enum, consider this example:

```js
enum MyEnum {
  ONE, // 0
  TWO // 1
}

/**
 * Obtains a union of all dictionary values
 */
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]


/**
 * Represents any enum type
 */
type EnumType = Record<string | number, string | number>

type EnumToObj<Enum extends EnumType> = Pick<
  {
    [Prop in keyof Enum]:
    (Enum[Prop] extends string | number
      ? `${Enum[Prop]}`
      : never)
  }, keyof Enum
>

{
  // {
  //   readonly ONE: "0";
  //   readonly TWO: "1";
  // }
  type Test = EnumToObj<typeof MyEnum>
}

type GetEnumValue<
  Enum extends EnumType,
  Index extends number,
  Obj extends EnumToObj<Enum> = EnumToObj<Enum>
  > =
  {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]:
    (`${Index}` extends Obj[Prop]
      ? Prop
      : never)
  }[keyof Enum];

{
  type Test = GetEnumValue<typeof MyEnum, 1> // TWO
}

type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false

type IsKeyValid<
  Index extends number,
  Enum extends EnumType
  > =
  IsNever<GetEnumValue<Enum, Index>> extends true
  ? never
  : Index

{
  type _ = IsKeyValid<1, typeof MyEnum> // 1
  type __ = IsKeyValid<2, typeof MyEnum> // never
}

function handleEnum<
  Index extends number,
  Enum extends EnumType
>(
  enEnum: Enum,
  index: IsKeyValid<Index, Enum>
): GetEnumValue<Enum, Index>
function handleEnum<
  Index extends number,
  Enum extends EnumType
>(enEnum: Enum, index: IsKeyValid<Index, Enum>) {
  return enEnum[index]
}

const x = handleEnum(MyEnum, 0) // "ONE"
const y = handleEnum(MyEnum, 1) // "TWO"

handleEnum(MyEnum, 2) // expected error
handleEnum(MyEnum, 'ONE') // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBeo4w)