# How to use an Angular pipe with complex parameters from the HTML template?

Tags: angular, luxon

I'm making an internationalized Angular application, so I implemented the [MatLuxonDateModule](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) for my MatDatepickers and it works fine.  But I also want to use a Luxon pipe whenever I format a date instead of the built-in date pipe so it works consistently in all browsers and cultures.

I made one that works fine:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DateTime, DateTimeFormatOptions } from 'luxon';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat',
})
export class LuxonDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: DateTime | Date, format: DateTimeFormatOptions = DateTime.DATE_SHORT): any {
    let dateTimeToUse: DateTime;
    if (value instanceof Date) {
      dateTimeToUse = DateTime.fromJSDate(value);
    } else {
      dateTimeToUse = value;
    }

    return dateTimeToUse.toLocaleString(format);
  }
}
```

Now I want to use it in the HTML template, like this:

```
{{ testDate | dateFormat: DateTime.DATE_MED_WITH_WEEKDAY }}
```

...but it doesn't know what "DateTime" is.  I can solve this by changing it to:

```
{{ testDate | dateFormat: formatToUse }}
```

...but then I have to declare a property like this in the .ts file every time I need to format a date:

```
  formatToUse: DateTimeFormatOptions = DateTime.DATE_MED_WITH_WEEKDAY;
```

This is really cumbersome.  **Is there a way to "import" Luxon in the template so I can reference `DateTime` on-the-fly?**

Edit: I suppose I could change the param to a string and add a huge switch case to the pipe to map to the Luxon formats, but that seems less than ideal.

Comment: i think `DateTime` is a enum so if you want to use it you have to set the hole enum to a object in your component like `public eDateTime = DateTime` and than you can use it like `{{ testDate | dateFormat: eDateTime.DATE_MED_WITH_WEEKDAY }}`

Comment: @DerHerrGammler That is definitely better than what I have.  I will do that if I can't figure out a way to do it without having to touch the .ts file at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

change your pipe:

```
export class LuxonDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: DateTime | Date, format: string = 'DATE_SHORT'): any {
    let dateTimeToUse: DateTime;
    if (value instanceof Date) {
      dateTimeToUse = DateTime.fromJSDate(value);
    } else {
      dateTimeToUse = value;
    }

    return dateTimeToUse.toLocaleString((<any>DateTime)[format]);
  }
}
```

and use your pipe like this:

```
{{ testDate | dateFormat: 'DATE_MED_WITH_WEEKDAY' }}
```

Comment: I like the idea to automatically convert the string, but it says "No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof DateTime'."

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.

Comment: Actually you were very close!  Works if I follow the first comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17381004/11991371).  I will edit and accept.

Comment: So close! I'm very pleased it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Juan / Roobot's original answer c. 2021 for v17 + with improved typing. This tweaks the API slightly where, as needed, the "format" option needs to be defined component side.

If Luxon updates with (or I missed) an easy type for the DATE_SHORT, etc. values, that could be used instead.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DateTime, DateTimeFormatOptions } from 'luxon';

@Pipe({
    name: 'luxonDate',
    standalone: true,
})
export class LuxonDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(
        value: string | DateTime | Date,
        format: DateTimeFormatOptions = DateTime['DATE_SHORT'],
    ): string {
        let useValue: DateTime;
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            useValue = DateTime.fromISO(value);
        } else if (value instanceof Date) {
            useValue = DateTime.fromJSDate(value);
        } else {
            useValue = value;
        }
        if (useValue.isValid) {
            return useValue.toLocaleString(format);
        }
        throw EvalError("couldn't coerce value to DateTime", { cause: value });
    }
}
```