# Best way to cast an object to a TypeScript Enum Value

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Is there an easy/best practice way to cast an `any` value to a TypeScript Enum and throw an exception if there is no value.

As an example

You have an express request object and are using the `query.option` value.  Your application knows it only has two valid states a|b.  However, the reality of the internet and request object is that it can be many things (undefined, a, b, foo).

```
enum OPTIONS_ENUM {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b'
}

function handleRequest(req: Request): OPTIONS_ENUM {
  // This will error because query.option is an any
  return OPTIONS_ENUM[req.query?.option]
}
```

What I have been doing seems a little verbose.  I have a "cast" function next to each enum that will throw if the ENUM does not have a value.

```
function castToOptionsEnum(option: any): OPTIONS_ENUM {
  if (!Object.values(OPTIONS_ENUM)?.includes(option)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid Value for option, must be one of ${Object.values(OPTIONS_ENUM)}`)
  }
 
  // @ts-ignore
  return OPTIONS_ENUM[option]
}

function handleRequest(req: Request) {
  // This will error because the option query is unknowable 
  return castToOptionsEnum(req.query?.option)
}
```

Comment: Other related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript/41548441#41548441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can "simply" cast `option` to `OPTIONS_ENUM` when accessing `OPTIONS_ENUM` in `castToOptionsEnum`:

```
function castToOptionsEnum(option: any): OPTIONS_ENUM {
    if (!Object.values(OPTIONS_ENUM)?.includes(option)) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid Value for option, must be one of ${Object.values(OPTIONS_ENUM)}`);
    }

    return OPTIONS_ENUM[option as OPTIONS_ENUM];
}
```

This will remove any compile errors (I would suggest to remove `// @ts-ignore` aswell, since it "hides" compile errors - but that's up to you ^^).

Comment: Any idea on a way to avoid the need for a casting function ?