# converting string value to enum type value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, index-signature

I have created a enum in typescript:

```
export enum ProductType {
  FRUIT,
  CLOTH,
}
```

I wonder if I receive string value `fruit` and `cloth`, how can I convert the string to the enum type. Here is what I tried:

```
const value: string = 'fruit';

// compiler error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'
const productType: ProductType = ProductType[value.toUpperCase()];
```

But I get compiler error pointing to `ProductType[value.toUpperCase()]`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'
```

What is the right way to convert string to enum type in typescript?

Comment: Hey, have you tried this solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56076148/8763644. I would also consider erasing const and using **var** instead.

Comment: Is the goal that the compiler should *know* that the value is literally `"fruit"` and that therefore the uppercase version is `"FRUIT"` and a known key of `ProductType`?  That is, if you wrote `"froot"` accidentally, you'd want a compiler error?  If so then you could possibly do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4pew), but this seems like an odd thing to do.  If that *is* what you want then I could write up an answer explaining it.  If it is *not*, could you clarify more, possibly with some other examples?

Comment: @ahmetgül `var` is a thing of the past ;)

Comment: Hey @MikeS., thanks for the information. Actually, I know that var is kind of a code smell. However, for the current topic, when I found some working examples and they all used "var". In addition to that, I saw that a user comment an answer to imply similar to that "did not work with const enum and worked with var". That's why I typed it at the end. If you have a different solution, I would love to learn :)

Comment: @ahmetgül Fair enough ;) The Question you linked seems to be an almost exact duplicate, so I marked it as such.

Comment: Thanks, I used the solution from @ahmetgül's link. It works.