# How can I pass an enum to a generic function and return the enum type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a function that safely casts a value to an enum: if the value is correct for the enum, return that, if not, return undefined.  I'm having troubles getting the correct type out of the function however (the functionality works, but ends up with the wrong return type).

This is the function I am trying:

```
function asEnum<ItemT, EnumT extends { [K in symbol]: ItemT }>(
  value: unknown,
  enumType: EnumT,
): EnumT | undefined {
  if( Object.values(enumType).includes(value) ) {
    return value as EnumT
  }
  return undefined
}
```

Consider this call setup:

```
enum MyEnum {
  a = "eh",
  b = "bee",
  c = "see",
}

function main() {
  const value = "bee"
  const ev = asEnum(value, MyEnum)
```

The problem is that the `asEnum` function, and thus `ev`, has resolved to the type `typeof MyEnum | undefined` rather than `MyEnum | undefined`. I understand why this happens, but am not certain how to fix it.

Is there someway to get the `MyEnum` type from a type of `typeof MyEnum`?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you expecting `ev` to be `MyEnum` or `MyEnum.b` in the example in which `value = "bee"`? I'm assuming the latter based on the `asEnum` function name, but the return type is `EnumT` which would imply the former. Either way, this question may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/17380845/9987590

Comment: Why are you using `symbol` here?

Comment: I'd think [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL32KN) is what you're looking for.  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @nate-kumar I'm expecting the result to be MyEnum.b. I wrote "EnumT" as the return since I don't know what type it should be and thought that was correct.