# How to get enum from numeric enum with a matching string in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
export enum OperationType {
  HEAL = 1,
  ATTACK
  DEFEND = 20,
  RETREAT,
  // ...plus 30 more values of varying numbers.
};
```

I have the above *numeric* enum in TypeScript.

I have a string `DEFEND`, I want to get the enum equivalent from `OperationType` with this `DEFEND` string. Is there a way to get the enum easily and reliably, other than creating a function and manually do a big switch/if-else loop to return the enum itself and maintaining that?

Edit:
This is my current code to loop through each of the enums to use it like `OperationType["DEFEND"]`:

```
Object.keys(OperationType).filter((v) => isNaN(Number(v))).map((value) => { 
    return <MenuOption onSelect={() => setOperationType(OperationType[value])} text={value} />
})
```

and I am getting the following error for `OperationType[value]`, `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)`.

I am assuming `OperationType[value]`'s `value` is failing because it expects a string from key that matches `OperationType` enums and not just "any" string. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey in **C#**? This is typescript

Comment: My bad. @Dimava in C# there are several hundred of these types of questions a day, so I'm a bit quick on the trigger. That said, I'm sure there's a dupe for TypeScript too.

Comment: [How do I convert a string to enum in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17380845/215552) for instance...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to enum in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: The handbook actually [suggests not using enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums) — example: https://tsplay.dev/wXv6Om

Answer (score 1):

Enums in TS are bidirectional

```
// compiled code:
export var OperationType;
(function (OperationType) {
    OperationType[OperationType["HEAL"] = 1] = "HEAL";
    OperationType[OperationType["ATTACK"] = 2] = "ATTACK";
    OperationType[OperationType["DEFEND"] = 20] = "DEFEND";
    OperationType[OperationType["RETREAT"] = 21] = "RETREAT";
    // ...plus 30 more values of varying numbers.
})(OperationType || (OperationType = {}));
;
```

so that's just

```
let d: OperationType[ /*DEFEND*/ 20 ] // 'DEFEND'
```